# Best test to compare cell population counts across patient groups

Tags: mixed-model, count-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, fishers-exact-test

Given a data frame structure similar to the following:

```
   Population_ID         Sample_ID Treatment Subject_ID Cells_in_Sample Total_in_Sample Percentage
1              1  patient1_sample1        No   patient1               4             630  0.6349206
2              1  patient2_sample1       Yes   patient2               0             630  0.0000000
3              1  patient3_sample1       Yes   patient3               0             630  0.0000000
4              1  patient4_sample1       Yes   patient4               1             630  0.1587302
5              1  patient5_sample1       Yes   patient5               0             630  0.0000000
6              1  patient6_sample1       Yes   patient6               1             630  0.1587302
7              1  patient7_sample1        No   patient7               0             630  0.0000000
8              1  patient8_sample1        No   patient8               1             630  0.1587302
9              1  patient9_sample1       Yes   patient9               2             630  0.3174603
10             1 patient10_sample1        No  patient10              14             630  2.2222222
11             1 patient11_sample1        No  patient11              12             630  1.9047619
12             1 patient12_sample1        No  patient12               3             630  0.4761905
...
```

I want to see if there is any cell population over-represented in one group of patients vs other(s).

What I have here is a long data frame with multiple cell populations (above only showing one) and their counts per sample (over the total number of cells in that sample). I want to see if any cell population is more prevalent in one Treatment group vs the other.

I would probably jutst perform on a population basis a t-test or Wilcoxon test (after testing normality and homoscedasticity), and then correct for multiple testing using the Benjamini-Hochberg correction.

But I am wondering whether a hypergeometric test would be more suitable. Or better yet, some linear mixed model to account for the patient random effect.

What would be the most suitable in this case and why? Note that I have no null hypotheses, I just want to make an exploratory tool that I want to generalize for more upcoming experiments of this kind.

In this sense, I want something extendable to cases where the response variable might not be just 2 levels (like treatment vs no treatment here)... so if Wilcoxon, for example, is the most suitable test, I would do Kruskal-Wallis for multiple levels and Wilcoxon for each pair.

There might also be cases where patient information is not available... so if a mixed model, for example, is the most suitable, I would do a regular linear model without random effect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to analyze single-cell data or equivalent. Please refer to the following two pages. This is still an evolving field and with active investigation, there is no defined test.

R-based analysis:
https://github.com/stemangiola/sccomp

Python-based analysis:
https://www.sc-best-practices.org/conditions/compositional.html